# How can you delete the first and fifth columns from 100 CSV files with EmEditor?

Tags: csv, emeditor

I have about 100 **CSV** (comma-separated) files. A sample CSV file is:

```
1,222,33,444,5
6,777,88,999,0
```

What is the best way to remove the first and fifth columns from all these CSV files with **EmEditor**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a macro to delete the first and fifth columns from a CSV document. After you open a CSV file with **EmEditor** (v21.0.0 or later), ensure the macro file works with one CSV document. To run a macro, save the code below as, for instance, `RemoveColumn.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run RemoveColumn.jsee** in the **Macros** menu.

`RemoveColumn.jsee`

```
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(22528); // select CSV mode
document.DeleteColumn( 5 );  // Delete Column 5
document.DeleteColumn( 1 );  // Delete Column 1
```

After you confirm the macro works, we will apply the macro to 100 CSV files.

To do this, select **Run with Temporary Options** on the **Macros** menu, ensure `RemoveColumn.jsee` is already specified in the **Macro** text box, set the **Run the macro against each opened document** and **Save and close each document after running the macro** options, drag and drop (or click the **Add** button and select) all CSV files you want to apply the macro, and click **Run**.

[image: EmEditor - Macro Temporary Options]

This should remove the first and fifth columns from all the specified CSV files.