# Command for deleting multiple columns based on header name with EmEditor?

Tags: csv, emeditor

I am looking for a way to use macros to remove certain columns from multiple csv files based on header names.

I found this previous answered question: [How can you delete the first and fifth columns from 100 CSV files with EmEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68718643/how-can-you-delete-the-first-and-fifth-columns-from-100-csv-files-with-emeditor)

But that only work with the column number.

I tried creating a macro like this:

````
document.DeleteColumn( Example1 );  // Delete Column With Header Example1
document.DeleteColumn( Example2 );  // Delete Column With Header Example2``` 


But I then get an error saying the example string is unspecified.

Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter of `DeleteColumn()` must be an integer value.
Here is a JavaScript macro to delete two columns specified by the header names.

```
asHeader = ["Example1", "Example2"];

function DeleteColumnByString( sHeader )
{
    document.selection.StartOfDocument();
    nMaxCol = document.GetColumns();
    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosCellLogical, nMaxCol, 1, true );
    if( document.selection.Find( sHeader,eeFindNext | eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceSelOnly,0) ) {
        iCol = document.selection.GetActivePointX( eePosCellLogical );
        document.selection.Collapse();
        document.DeleteColumn( iCol );
    }
}

for( i = 0; i < asHeader.length; ++i ) {
    DeleteColumnByString( asHeader[i] );
}
```

To run a macro, save the code below as, for instance, `RemoveColumn.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run RemoveColumn.jsee** in the **Macros** menu.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to make a script that states which columns to keep by header and then delete all other columns that does not include specified headers?

Comment: I manually added all my columns 200+ in the script but not all my csv files contains the same columns/headers and if the specified headers don't exist in the file the macro stops