# How can I sort the 2nd column from 100 CSV files with EmEditor?

Tags: emeditor, itemeditor

I have over 100 csv files where I need to sort the all the data in the 2nd column and I have some trouble figuring out how.

I was able to use this guide to delete specific columns

[How can you delete the first and fifth columns from 100 CSV files with EmEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68718643/how-can-you-delete-the-first-and-fifth-columns-from-100-csv-files-with-emeditor)

And also tried using some of the sort commands from the website without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

The Advanced Sort feature can sort all opened documents.

Open Sort | Advanced Sort... and change the **Column** dropdown to the 2nd column. Change **How to Sort** to the method you need. Then test that this sort works on a single CSV document.

Now open all 100 files. This time, check **Apply to all documents in the group** in Advanced Sort and click Sort Now.

[image]